# How to programmatically build a ForEach input?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I have written a custom `JSR223 PostProcessor` in order deduplicate a `JSON Extractor` array, and then build all of the needed variables for a `ForEach Controller`

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

def previousValuesMatchNrAsString = vars.get("distinctServiceIds_matchNr");
def previousValuesMatchNr = previousValuesMatchNrAsString ? previousValuesMatchNrAsString.toInteger() : 0;
for(i = 1; i <= previousValuesMatchNr; i++) {
    vars.remove("distinctServiceIds_" + i);
}
vars.remove("distinctServiceIds_ALL");
vars.remove("distinctServiceIds_matchNr");

def values = vars.get("serviceIds_ALL").split(",");
def newValues = Arrays.stream(values).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
def newValuesCount = newValues.size();
def joinesNewValues = String.join(",", newValues);
vars.put("distinctServiceIds_ALL", joinesNewValues);
newValues.eachWithIndex { var, idx -> vars.put("distinctServiceIds_" + (idx + 1), var) };
vars.put("distinctServiceIds_matchNr", newValuesCount.toString());
```

I have to cleanup variables first, because this `JSR223 PostProcessor` runs into another `ForEach Controller`, and then I have to populate `distinctServiceIds_ALL`, `distinctServiceIds_matchNr` and all of the indexed variables in order to use `distinctServiceIds` as "Input variable prefix" for my `ForEach Controller`.

Although this works, it seems very hacky to me and I wonder if there's some Groovy function, or something else, to do all of that work.

Comment: Why not use `serviceIds`  for second controller input?

Comment: @user7294900 because I need to deduplicate the array

Comment: If it works but you don't like the java-ness, i'd move that over to the code review stack exchange?  If you want to change things, i'd start with using groovy features (e.g. use "var_${i+i}" GStrings, get rid of the stream stuff in the middle) and get rid of the copy-and-paste imperativeness (e.g. accumualte the keys to remove, than do a keys.each{ vars.remove it }; build a map for adding and use putAll, ...)

Answer (score 0):

there are many additional methods defined in groovy

as soon as vars contains type of [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) to remove old vars you could collect required entries from iterator and call remove for each one

the extension groovy methods for iterator could be found in [groovy docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Iterator.html)

```
vars.getIterator().findAll{ it.getKey().startsWith('distinctServiceIds_') }.each{
    vars.remove(it.getKey())
}
```

because of groovy it could be simplified to this:

```
vars.iterator.findAll{ it.key.startsWith('distinctServiceIds_') }.each{
    vars.remove(it.key)
}
```

---

the same with other generic types: List, Maps, etc

collecting unique values and transforming to map:

```
def values = [111,222,333,444,444,444,444]
def valMap = values.unique().indexed().collectEntries{k,v-> ['distinctServiceIds_'+(k+1),v] }
vars.putAll(valMap)
```

---

so, check [groovy jdk extension documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/)

Comment: Thanks for answering, unfortunately, `vars` is of type `JMeterVariables` and does not implement `Map`: https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html

Comment: modified answer for this type